# How to serve phpmyadmin over https with nginx

Tags: nginx, phpmyadmin

How can I correctly configure nginx and phpmyadmin? I've configured nginx and can access phpmyadmin login page through nginx but unable to login, when I try to login it shows `Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.`

[image]

I'm accessing through https://example.com/phpmyadmin/

and this is the nginx config

```
location /myphpadminroute/{
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header host $host;
    proxy_pass_request_headers      on;

    root path_to_phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin/;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/; # apache is running on 8080
}
```

The login is working fine when using apache url either `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/` or `https://localhost:8443/phpmyadmin/`

I've also tried with `proxy_pass https://localhost:8443/phpmyadmin/;` in nginx but same error rises.

Whether it is nginx configuration problem or phpmyadmin I just couldn't figure it out.

Edit: The cookie path is not correct `phpMyAdmin_https=utd7tbihn9qp9r4e0f0dvj6tpo; path=/phpmyadmin/; secure; HttpOnly` and it's working fine if I change nginx path to `/phpMyAdmin/` now how can I change cookie path in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally it's working perfectly fine.

For those who are also facing this type of problem the trick is to just set variable in `config.inc.php` `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']` to the url that your user should see

for example `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = https://example.com/myphpadminroute`